# WordPress attachment display settings only allows "full-size"

Tags: wordpress, image

I have been developing a site using the Twenty-Sixteen theme.  I just realized that I only have the "Full Size" option when I insert an image to a Page or Post.
[image: Full Size only option]

I've only found one question on wp.SE, but it relates to custom image sizes.  I have not tried to set up custom image sizes, or done anything of the like.

I would expect that out of the box, WordPress would have allowed me to have four different choices for attachment size, as normal.  In my Media Settings, everything looks typical (see below):
[image: display settings]

I can't guess where else to look to see if something is set incorrectly.  I searched through my child functions.php file but I didn't find anything that would affect image sizes.

Can anyone please advise me where else I could troubleshoot, so I can repair this problem and see image size choices as they should default (like when WordPress is installed)?